# Global values - anti-pattern?

Tags: node.js

I was recently told, that accessing `process.env` values anywhere else, but start-up file is an anti-pattern. Is that true? If so, how am I supposed to access values assigned there? Should I assign them to `global` scope? I don't really understand WHY this would be anti-pattern, could someone explain this to me?

Comment: What is a "start-up file"? I mean, whomever told you this apparently _also_ has ideas on how apps should be structured. Sounds pretty dogmatic to me, but that's just my opinion (which is also why your question, albeit valid, may get closed for being primarily opinion-based). As a counter-argument, there are well-known and often-used modules, like [`debug`](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug), that access `process.env`.

Comment: A start-up script is most likely script to which `npm start` points to. But I agree, some modules even access those vals, so I can't get my head around reason why that'd be something not well seen, to use `process.env`s around the codebase.

Comment: Using environment variables in a global config file makes sense, but using them exclusively in a start-up file doesn't, precisely because of the reason you're stating: how are you supposed to access them from other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config variables from environment tend to be non-readable often. So, you can possibly end up with something like `process.env.PRODUCTION_DATABASES_MONGO_PORT` that will mess up your code. And if your have a lot of `process.env`-s in different files it might be hard to understand what possible options are (should you run `NODE_ENV=dev node index` or `NODE_ENV=development node index` or `FOO=true node index`?).

As most simple solution that doesn't require any dependency injection you can simply create `config.js` in the root folder with something like:

```
module.exports = {
  databases: {
    mongo: {
      port: process.env.BLAH_BLAH_BLAH
    }
  }
  // ...
};
```

and just require it wherever you want.

Comment: @robertklep no. Have a look at this real mongo port env variable from one project where I was working: `PRODUCTION_MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR`. It's easy to understand what does it mean but I don't believe it's great to have such names somewhere in the code (especially if you need to use it many times). It's confusing a bit from programmer's point of view (but can be totally ok for devops who have created it). So I just propose to encapsulate all this stuff in config file and use plain objects i.e. `config.databases.mongo.port` instead of `process.env.PRODUCTION_MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR`

Comment: I've never come across such weirdly named environment variables, the whole point being that you'd use something like `process.env.MONGO_URI` which would point to different databases depending on production versus development, etc. I see your point that those kinds of variables shouldn't be used in different files, but IMO they shouldn't be used at all :)

Comment: @robertklep you damn right about "they should be used at all" )

Comment: thank you, for your valid input, although I believe that's not much related to what I was told. It was pointed to me, on my job interview. Although I missed it at first, because I focused on other aspects of the feedback I received. But still - this is completely valid point, to make a config file, instead of using `process.env` vals globally.